# Cannot convert date to the right format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, datetime, parsing

I want to convert "query" to "09/08/2019". The code below is throwing "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" (IsDate(query) returns true though):

```
query = "09 August 2019 00:00:00"

Dim Ddate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(query, "dd/M/yyyy", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

How can I get the date in the required format? thanks

Comment: `ParseExact()` means exactly as the supplied format. You're providing a DateTime Format that doesn't match the input. You can use TryParse instead. Something like: `Dim dt as Date if Date.TryParse("09 August 2019 00:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, dt) then Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy")) end if`. Specify whether the date should be interpreted as Local or Universal setting the `DateTimeStyles` argument. Use DateTime objects to store dates. Convert to string when needed for presentation only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with below code snippet.

C#

```
IFormatProvider CultureToUse = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime d4, d5;
Boolean b1 = DateTime.TryParse(selected_date, out d4);
Boolean b2 = DateTime.TryParse(selected_date, CultureToUse, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d5);
// you can use any one of the above
// please check value in d4 and d5
```

VB

```
  Dim CultureToUse As IFormatProvider = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", True)
  Dim d4, d5 As DateTime
    Dim b1 As Boolean = DateTime.TryParse(selected_date, d4)
    Dim b2 As Boolean = DateTime.TryParse(selected_date, CultureToUse, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, d5)
// you can use any one of the above
// please check value in d4 and d5
```